# How to append the whole <div>

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
    <div class="rows">
       <input type="text" id="ip1" class="ip1">
       <input type="text" id="ip2" class="ip2">
       <input type="button" value="Delete" id="del" class="del">                        
    </div><!--Rows-->

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(e){
         $("#add").click(function(e){
            $(".rows").append('<input type="text" id="ip1" class="ip1">'+
            '<input type="text" id="ip1" class="ip1">'+
            '<input type="button" alue="Delete" id="del" class="del">');
         });
      });
    </script>
```

I Did this using this method. Is there any other good method like appending the whole div.
and i need to delete that row alone if i click delete button,
Thanks

Comment: You have duplicate ids for dom. That is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, I ll do that but i need to append like giving that div name. Is that is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid duplicated id's you can do that in this way : http://jsbin.com/xotoyogo/1/edit?html,js,output

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function(e){
         $("#add").click(function(e){
           var newId = $('.row').length + 1;

           $(".container")
           .append('<div class="row"><input type="text" id="ip' + newId+'" class="ip1"> '+
          '<input type="text" id="ip'+newId+'" class="ip1"> '+
          '<input type="button" value="Delete" id="del'+newId+'" class="del"></div>');
         });
      });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
       <input type="text" id="ip1" class="ip1">
       <input type="text" id="ip2" class="ip2">
       <input type="button" value="Delete" id="del" class="del"> 

    </div><!--Rows-->
  </div>
  <button id="add">add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $("#add").click(function(e){
     var clone = $(".rows:first").clone();
     $(".rows:last").after(clone);
   });
   $(document).on('click','.del', function(){
      if ($('.rows').length > 1) 
       $(this).closest('.rows').remove();
   })
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HLypn/7/)

*Side note: id should be unique in a document, so you should use classes in dynamically added templates*

Comment: The current ".rows" in his example is just a single row. It needs fixing too. Good use of delegation for the delete though :)

Comment: There is a problem with your fiddle. Each time the children will get doubled

Comment: @AnoopJoshi oh yes, it should've been after -_-

Comment: Making the first delete button *do nothing* is not a great UI experience. Best use a template element so even the first one can be deleted (or at least hide that delete button). :)

Answer (score 0):

You need another level of `div`:

```
<div class="rows">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" id="ip1" class="ip1">
        <input type="text" id="ip2" class="ip2">
        <input type="button" value="Delete" id="del" class="del">                        
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your script would be:

```
  $(document).ready(function(e){
     $("#add").click(function(e){
       $(".rows").append('<div class="row"><input type="text" id="ip1" class="ip1">'+
                        '<input type="text" id="ip1" class="ip1">'+
                        '<input type="button" alue="Delete" id="del" class="del">' +
                        '</div>');
     });
  });
```

You also need to fix the code so that you assign unique IDs in each row. Or leave out the IDs -- you probably don't need them.

To delete, you need to use delegation with `.on()`, so that it will apply to elements added dynamically.

```
$(".rows").on("click", ".del", function() {
    $(this).closest(".row").remove();
});
```

Comment: barmar Thanks can u help me in delete
if i click delete button only that row should delete.

Comment: The delete addition will not work as `.del` is only applied to elements that exist at that time. Use a delegated event.

Comment: Good catch, I've fixed it to use delegation.

Comment: Thanks everyone i did it and Tilwin Joy I feel ur code is bit difficult for me, coz i m jus started to study jquery. any how thanks every one.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a separate element for the template (so you can delete all records)

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rBLkp/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $("#add").click(function(e){
     $(".rows:last").append($('#template').html());
   });
   $(document).on('click','.del', function(){
      $(this).closest('.row').remove();
   })
});
```

### Notes:

- Get rid of the IDs as they cannot be duplicated
- I added a row wrapper to group the controls into rows
- I store the template row as a dummy script block of unknown type (so the browser ignores it)
- It uses a delegated `on` to catch the delete buttons

If you need unique ids, use a placeholder in the template and use simple text replacement to insert it.

e.g.

```
$(".rows:last").append($('#template').html().replace("{id}", yourNewIdHere));
```

### Delegated `on` event handler (explanation):

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click','.del', function(){event code});
```

A delegated event handler works by listening for events that bubble up to a non-changing ancestor. It *then* applies the jQuery filter, it *then* applies the function to any elements *that caused the event in the first place*. This is a great way of attaching to elements that do not exist yet.

`document` is the default place to connect it if there is no closer "non-changing" ancestor. In your example you could connect it to `.rows`

e.g.

```
$('.rows').on('click','.del', function(){event code});
```

Note: Never connect a delegated event handler to `'body'` as it has odd behavior with some events.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use unique id or in this case use class ,that is enough to handle the dom element

```
var count = 0;
$("#add").click(function (e) {
    count++;

       $(".rows").append('<div><input type="text" id=ip' + count + ' class=ip' + count + '/><input type="text" id="ipsecond' + count + ' class="ipsecond' + count + '/> <input type="button" alue="Delete"  class="del"value ="delete"/></div>');


});
```

### [DEMO DELETE](http://jsfiddle.net/aa99j/12/)

FOR delete

```
$(".rows").on("click",".del",function(){
$(this).closest("div").remove();

});
```