# How to manipulate rows with the id attribute appended with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

Before sorry for my bad english

I have an input table, with row id, when the onchange input affects the next input in row 1. Now this row can be added, I have made an increment for each row added, so the id row will be added to row2, row3 and so on. the problem here is, how to manipulate rows that have been added

here is the view

```
<table class="table-common mb-4">
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Account</th>
                <th>Tax</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row1" class="item">
                <td>
                    <select name="product[]" class="form-control form-control-select2 product">
                        <option value="">Choose one</option>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
                            $selected = getValue('productId', $row) == $productId->id ? 'selected' : NULL;

                            echo "<option value='{$productId->id}'>{$productId->code} - {$productId->name}</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control description"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control form-control-decimal quantity"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="unitPrice[]" class="form-control form-control-decimal unitPrice"></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="account[]" class="form-control form-control-select2 account">
                        <option value="">Choose one</option>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($accountIds as $accountId) {
                            $selected = getValue('accountId', $row) == $accountId->id ? 'selected' : NULL;

                            echo "<option value='{$accountId->id}'>{$accountId->code} - {$accountId->name}</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="tax[]" class="form-control form-control-select2 tax">
                        <option value="">Choose one</option>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($taxIds as $taxId) {
                            $selected = getValue('taxId', $row) == $taxId->id ? 'selected' : NULL;

                            echo "<option value='{$taxId->id}'>{$taxId->name} - {$taxId->amount}</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="totalPrice[]" class="form-control form-control-decimal totalPrice" readonly></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

this when click Add More

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    let previousRow = $("tr:last").attr("id")
    let counter = previousRow.charAt(3)
    let count = parseInt(counter)
    let no = 0
    $("#addMore").on('click', (e) => {
        count ++
        no = count

        $(".table-common").append(`
            <tr id="row${count}" class="item">
                <td>
                    <select name="product[]" class="form-control form-control-select2 product">
                        <option value="">Choose one</option>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
                            $selected = getValue('productId', $row) == $productId->id ? 'selected' : NULL;

                            echo "<option value='{$productId->id}'>{$productId->code} - {$productId->name}</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control description"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control form-control-decimal quantity"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="unitPrice[]" class="form-control form-control-decimal unitPrice"></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="account[]" class="form-control form-control-select2 account">
                        <option value="">Choose one</option>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($accountIds as $accountId) {
                            $selected = getValue('accountId', $row) == $accountId->id ? 'selected' : NULL;

                            echo "<option value='{$accountId->id}'>{$accountId->code} - {$accountId->name}</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="tax[]" class="form-control form-control-select2 tax">
                        <option value="">Choose one</option>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($taxIds as $taxId) {
                            $selected = getValue('taxId', $row) == $taxId->id ? 'selected' : NULL;

                            echo "<option value='{$taxId->id}'>{$taxId->name} - {$taxId->amount}</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="totalPrice[]" class="form-control form-control-decimal totalPrice" readonly></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete"><i class="icon ion-close-round"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
        `)
    })

    $(`#row1 .product`).on("change", () => {
        let productId = $(".product option:selected").val()

        $.ajax({
            url: `<?php echo base_url("accounting/configurations/products/index/") ?>${productId}`,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: (data) => {
                $("#row1 .description").val(data.description)
                $("#row1 .description").val()
                $("#row1 .unitPrice").val(data.sellPrice)
                $("#row1 .sellAccountId").val(data.sellAccountId)
                $("#row1 .sellTaxId").val(data.sellTaxId)
            }
        })
    })
});
```

So, how to manipulate other row when it's added?

Comment: Why did you tag this under php?

Comment: because it contains php and jquery, so I tagged both

Comment: `So, how to manipulate other row when it's added?`. Manipulate how?

Comment: can be seen, each row has an id, so how to get the newly added row id?

Comment: Append like in this link given: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651890/how-to-append-the-whole-div Or , on add row, you should call ajax and create the whole HTML there and then whatever you get, append that in the table. That's a simple way because you are appending PHP generated loops. Also, you had space between  `count++;` Remove that space.

Answer (score 0):

after appending the row call a new function passing the object you want to manipulate:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    let previousRow = $("tr:last").attr("id")
    let counter = previousRow.charAt(3)
    let count = parseInt(counter)
    let no = 0
    $("#addMore").on('click', (e) => {
        count ++
        no = count

        $(".table-common").append(`
            <tr id="row${count}" class="item">
                <td>
                    <select name="product[]" class="form-control form-control-select2 product">
                        <option value="">Choose one</option>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
                            $selected = getValue('productId', $row) == $productId->id ? 'selected' : NULL;

                            echo "<option value='{$productId->id}'>{$productId->code} - {$productId->name}</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control description"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control form-control-decimal quantity"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="unitPrice[]" class="form-control form-control-decimal unitPrice"></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="account[]" class="form-control form-control-select2 account">
                        <option value="">Choose one</option>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($accountIds as $accountId) {
                            $selected = getValue('accountId', $row) == $accountId->id ? 'selected' : NULL;

                            echo "<option value='{$accountId->id}'>{$accountId->code} - {$accountId->name}</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="tax[]" class="form-control form-control-select2 tax">
                        <option value="">Choose one</option>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($taxIds as $taxId) {
                            $selected = getValue('taxId', $row) == $taxId->id ? 'selected' : NULL;

                            echo "<option value='{$taxId->id}'>{$taxId->name} - {$taxId->amount}</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="totalPrice[]" class="form-control form-control-decimal totalPrice" readonly></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete"><i class="icon ion-close-round"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
        `)
        manipulateRow($("#row${count}"))
    })



function manipulateRow(obj){
    obj.find('.product').on("change", () => {
        let productId = obj.find(".product option:selected").val()

        $.ajax({
            url: `<?php echo base_url("accounting/configurations/products/index/") ?>${productId}`,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: (data) => {
                obj.find(".description").val(data.description)
               obj.find(".description").val()
                obj.find(".unitPrice").val(data.sellPrice)
                obj.find(" .sellAccountId").val(data.sellAccountId)
                obj.find(".sellTaxId").val(data.sellTaxId)
            }
        })
    })
  }
});
```